# Sistema de ofertas automáticas PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy en el proceso de escribir una secuencia de comandos para la oferta automática de un artículo. Creo que la forma más fácil de describir lo que estoy tratando de hacer es darle un escenario. Asumiendo incrementos de $1,000:

````
Precio solicitado: $1,000
Postor 1: Puja Máxima de $4,000 -> Puja Máxima: $1,000
Postor 2: Puja Máxima de $3,000 -> Puja Máxima: $3,000 -> [AUTO PUJADOR 1] Puja Máxima: $4,000
Postor 3: Puja Máxima de $8,000 -> Puja Máxima: $5,000
Postor 4: Puja Máxima de $10,000 -> [PUJADOR AUTOMÁTICO 3] Puja Alta: $8,000 -> Puja Alta: $9,000```
````

Estoy tratando de encontrar un bucle para pasar por ellos, pero no estoy exactamente seguro de cómo hacerlo. Se me ocurrió un bucle que funcionaría para cada oferta, pero me gustaría omitir hacer cada incremento de $ 1,000 y, en cambio, aumentar la oferta más alta en función de las ofertas máximas.

Tengo una tabla configurada: pujas . Este fue el bucle en el que pensé:

- Insertar nueva oferta
- Bucle de inicio
- $mayor= obtener la oferta actual más alta de la tabla de ofertas
- $segumayor= obtener la oferta máxima más baja donde oferta máxima >
  $ alta de ofertas máximas
- if ($segumayor >= ($mayor + incremento) Insertar en ofertas
- else // asume que ya tienes la oferta más alta romper bucle
- bucle final

Esto funcionaría, pero como dije, esto seguiría insertando todos los incrementos de $1,000. Prefiero que funcione de la manera que mostré arriba. ¿Alguna sugerencia?